# Type casting to Long

Tags: android, string, casting, android-emulator, long-integer

I've created a timer that will accept a specified time value from user through edittext box and pass to the CountDownTimer(). This method expect a long value thats why i converted it into long but when i add this long convertion the android emulator shows an error unfortunately stopped.And here is my code

```
EditText ti=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);
Editable i = ti.getText();
String p=i.toString();
long x=Long.parseLong(p);

final TextView mCounter1TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter1);
final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(x, 10) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mCounter1TextField.setText(" " + (millisUntilFinished)/ 1000 + ":");
    }

    public void onFinish() {  
        mp3.start ();      
        Log.d ("Splash", "LauncherActivity.onCreate - created MediaPlayer");
        cancel();
    }    
};

//Start Button1
btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Counter1.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the error that gets shown? Stack trace?

Comment: Its an android runtime error shown in a toast unfortunately stopped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an error to go on, the first thing I noticed is that you aren't catching a NumberFormatException on `parseLong()`

```
long x=0L;
try {
    x = Long.parseLong(p);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    // TODO: error report or something
}
```

Comment: when i add this exception with the declaration long x=0L; i got another error "Duplicate local variable"

Comment: You must have another variable `x` somewhere. You didn't do 'long x' on both lines shown above by accident?

Comment: when i removed that declaration i got another error and eclipse suggestion " create local variable 'x' "

Comment: Does it give you line numbers or anything? Variable names are pretty simple - without seeing your whole class it's impossible to tell what is going on.

Comment: i got nothing. when the program starts to execute these lines it shows an error unfortunately stopped

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string to an integer, i hope. First convert it to an int and then make it long.